# why isn't my ID being applied?

Tags: css, list

CSS:

```
#holidayclosings ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="holidayclosings">
<li>Saturday, December 24: <b>Closed</b></li>
...
```

So as far as I can tell the `#holidayclosings ul` rule has NO EFFECT. If I change it to just `ul` it works, but then it affects the entire page, not just this one list. Obviously I'm forgetting something, but I haven't had enough coffee and I'm drawing a blank. can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to select the `ul` element that is a descendant of the `#holidayclosings` element. Try:

```
#holidayclosings {
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
    background : red;
}
```

If you want to select an element in CSS by using a tag name and an identifier (notice there are no spaces between the tag name and the ID):

```
ul#holidayclosings {
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
    background : red;
}
```

However for elements that you are selecting with IDs this doesn't make sense since there can only be one of the element in the DOM. It's more useful for selecting elements by attribute:

```
ul.holidayclosings {
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
    background : red;
}
```

OR

```
ul[name="holidayclosings"] {
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
    background : red;
}
```

Comment: explanation and solution. perfect.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because that CSS rule `#holidayclosings ul` is looking for a `ul` within the element of an `id` of `holidayclosings`. To target the `ul` itself use: `#holidayclosings` or `ul#holidayclosings` (the latter is almost entirely redundant since there can only be *one* element of a given `id` within the document, so it's element-type doesn't matter).

The space between selectors is a [descendent selector (see the W3.org entry)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

Answer (score 1):

`#holidayclosings ul` will apply the enclosed styles to any ul's that are descendants of whatever element has the `#holidayclosings` id.

What you want is:

```
#holidayclosings {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:red;
}
```

An example of what one might use your original selector for:

```
<div id="holidayclosings">
    <ul>
        <li>Saturday, December 24: <b>Closed</b></li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Saturday, December 24: <b>Closed</b></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

In this case, the styles would apply to both of the ul's within the `#holidayclosings` div.

Answer (score 1):

you have an extraneous `ul` in your declaration. You can (but don't!) do `ul#holidayclosings` but right now your CSS declaration assumes the `ul` is a child of `#holidayclosings`

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
ul#holidayclosings {
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
    background : red;
}
```